# Why is the measure $\nu$ nonnegative here?

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity

> Let $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space, let $\{E_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ a collection of measurable sets, and $\{ c_{k}\}_{k=1}^n$ a collection of real numbers. For $E \in \mathfrak{M}$ define $$\nu(E) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{k} \mu(E \cap E_{k}).$$ Show that $\nu$ is a measure on $(X, \mathfrak{M})$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ and find its Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\nu / d\mu$.

Why is the measure $\nu$ even nonnegative here?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I think it can not be nonnegative as the $c_k$ are real numbers @Mars Plastic

Comment: Presumably $c_k$ need to be nonnegative themselves, and presumably you'd eliminate the zero ones since they don't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not assume that the $c_k$ are nonnegative, the statement is false. For $n=1$, $E_1=X$ and $c_1=-1$, you'd have $\nu=-\mu$, which is only nonnegative for $\mu(X)=0$.

However, even without the nonnegativity of the $c_k$, $\nu$ would still be a **signed** measure and it would indeed be absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.